# When do you use double datetime.datetime in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

This timestamp is used for bug logging.

```
import os.path
import datetime

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Tried to search but was unable to find anything related to this.  I would like to know when do you use double datetime method?

Comment: `datetime` is a class of the package `datetime`. If you use `import datetime`, you must reference the class as the double you see. Most use cases use `from datetime import datetime`, where you can reference the class directly and can use a single.

Comment: the first `datetime` is the package, the second `datetime` is the class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first `datetime` refers to the *library*, and the second to one of its *modules*.

Which should you use? It depends how you imported it. If you just imported the **library**, like this:

```py
import datetime
```

you will need to write the library name **again**, like this: `datetime.datetime.now()`. If you imported the module, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

you imported the module, so you can just use `datetime.now()` afterwards. Both are absolutely equal, it's up to you to decide which you choose.